# Best way to handle duplicate entry error

Tags: android, exception, appium, android-multidex

I'm trying to use Appium in my android studio project so I had to create a new test package and I had to add a new library in my dependencies for Appium:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:1.0.1'
    ...
}
```

And after that, when I tried to run my test relative to Appium or even when I tried to run my project I got this error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible.class
```

Indeed I found this duplicate class in package com.google.common.annotations, but I don't know what is the best practice to manage this type of error.

I tried to clean, rebuild I tried to find maybe a way to exclude this duplicate class, but at the moment I didn't find a good solution to fix my problem.